# Rails form action and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller action that requires parameters, and has to be accessed both through get and post.
with get it looks like:

`get 'cart/add:id,:qty' => 'cart#add',    as: :addToCart`

the controller action is:

```
def add
 product = Product.find(params[:id])

 if ::AddToCart.new(@cart, product, params[:qty]).execute
   flash[:succes] = "Product(s) added."
 else
   flash[:failure] = "Product cannot be added."
 end  

 redirect_to request.referer
end
```

how should the post route look like if i would like it to use the same action.

PS: i use the get version as a link_to when only one product is added, the post route is needed because the quantity will be unknown

Comment: Rails will make it hard for you to do this.  It's also poor design from a RESTful perspective.  _Don't_ use the same action and be happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make this strictly a post route. If you want, you can default the quantity to one when it isn't provided. Or, use ajax to post to the route with a quantity of one when they click the "add one" link. That way it can look and seem to behave like a regular link_to sort of link, but you'll still have the benefits of only updating data via POST and leaving all your actual GET requests idempotent.

Comment: OK i understand, then how should i aces post variables in controller? thought that i will be able to aces them through params[:]

Comment: Yes, you can access them through params. Watch your logs, at the beginning of each request, the logs should record exactly how the params are being passed. That should help you see how to access them in your controller.